# Query with distinct and max in SQL

Tags: mysql

I need a mysql query which will select all rows that contain "joe" in either the "name" or "quantity" column. It needs to be distinct among the "name" and "quantity" columns, which means that we will get the max value of quantity corressponding with each name as the below image:
[image]

The final table should also be sorted by id descending.
Please tell me know the way to do it with a mysql query.
Thanks

Comment: Under what circumstances might a string appear in an integer column?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use `not exists`

```
select * from table_name t1 
where 
not exists (
select 1 from table_name t2 where t1.name= t2.name and t1.quantity < t2.quantity
);
```

Another variation is to use `left join`

```
select t1.* from table_name t1 
left join table_name t2 on t2.name = t1.name  
and t1.quantity < t2.quantity 
where t2.id is null;
```

Comment: And the fastest way would be ... (option 3)

Comment: Well the left join better in performance than exists when you have indexed column. The optimizer can do the optimization however for a small set of data and when your table is relatively small and indexed then there is no difference between them. And if you know a better faster way why not add that as answer instead of commenting ?

Comment: Because typing on a phone is tedious and I figured you probably knew the method to which I was referring. It's covered in the manual after all.

Comment: I am not sure which method you are referring to is that `select t1.* from test t1 join (select name,max(quantity) as quantity from test  group by name)t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.quantity = t2.quantity ;` ? and if yes then I am sorry it uses derived select type and its not good while it comes for using index.